# App created in ionic doesnt launch the browser

Tags: ionic-framework, browser, ionic2, command-line-interface

I just created a draft app using ionic and wanted to see it on the browser using

```
ionic serve
```

but ran into an issue:
it kept failing to open the browser and I had to open Firefox manually. so I was curious if there is a way around this? managing permissions and stuff.. or I have to live with it!
Thanks for your insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ionic serve don't know which browser to run, so, add a default browser.

```
ionic serve -f firefox
```